Nested Loop IF resource contains key in Terraform
I would like to iterate over a list of values ONLY if the object contains a specific property. Is that possible?
For this use case I want to provision GitHub Repository Variables and Secrets if the local variable has the 'variables' property.
Locals.tf
locals {

  repos = {
    "terraform-tfe" : {
      description        = "Automation for Terraform Cloud"
      visibility         = "private"
    }
    "terraform-github" : {
      description        = "Automation for Github Repos"
      visibility         = "private"

    }
    "terraform-testapp" : {
      description        = "Test web app "
      visibility         = "private"

      variables = ["STORAGEACCOUNT","HOSTURL"]
      secrets   = ["CLIENTID", "CLIENTSECRET]
    }
  }
}

Main.tf
resource "github_repository" "repos" {

  for_each = local.repos

  name               = each.key
  description        = each.value.description
  visibility         = each.value.visibility

}

resource "github_actions_variable" "repository_variables" {

  for_each      = local.repos
  
  # IF each has 'variables' property
  
  repository = each.key
  # Iterate over variables in each.value.repositories

}

resource "github_actions_secrets" "repository_secrets" {

  for_each      = local.repos
  
  # IF each has 'secrets' property
  
  repository = each.key
  # Iterate over secrets in each.value.secrets

}


Have you checked these filtering elements using Terraform which might suit your scenario.

As mentioned in Filtering elements, a for expression can also include an optional if clause to filter elements from the source collection:
locals {
  repos = { ... }

  secrets = {
    for repo_name, repo in local.repos :
    repo_name => repo.secrets
    if can(repo.secrets)
  }
}

In this case, the can function returns false if the secrets property doesn't exist.
Full working example:
locals {
  repos = {
    "terraform-tfe" : {
      description = "Automation for Terraform Cloud"
      visibility  = "private"

      variables = [
        "STORAGEACCOUNT_1"
      ]
    }
    "terraform-github" : {
      description = "Automation for Github Repos"
      visibility  = "private"

      secrets = [
        "CLIENTID_1",
        "CLIENTSECRET_1"
      ]

    }
    "terraform-testapp" : {
      description = "Test web app "
      visibility  = "private"

      variables = [
        "STORAGEACCOUNT_2",
        "HOSTURL_2"
      ]

      secrets = [
        "CLIENTID_2",
        "CLIENTSECRET_2"
      ]
    }
  }

  secrets = {
    for repo_name, repo in local.repos :
    repo_name => repo.secrets
    if can(repo.secrets)
  }

  variables = {
    for repo_name, repo in local.repos :
    repo_name => repo.variables
    if can(repo.variables)
  }
}

output "secrets" {
  value       = local.secrets
  description = "Secret variables for all repos."
}

output "variables" {
  value       = local.variables
  description = "Variables for all repos."
}

Running terraform plan:
Changes to Outputs:
  + secrets   = {
      + terraform-github  = [
          + "CLIENTID_1",
          + "CLIENTSECRET_1",
        ]
      + terraform-testapp = [
          + "CLIENTID_2",
          + "CLIENTSECRET_2",
        ]
    }
  + variables = {
      + terraform-testapp = [
          + "STORAGEACCOUNT_2",
          + "HOSTURL_2",
        ]
      + terraform-tfe     = [
          + "STORAGEACCOUNT_1",
        ]
    }

You can apply this plan to save these new output values to the Terraform
state, without changing any real infrastructure.


Here is an example using a list instead of a map, this looks a lot cleaner then using nested maps, because you don't need to specify a key. Furthermore, I used the try() function to filter repositories that only contain secrets or variables to create both respectively.
locals {
  repos = [
    {
      name        = "terraform-tfe"
      description = "Automation for Terraform Cloud"
      visibility  = "private"
    },
    {
      name        = "terraform-github"
      description = "Automation for Github Repos"
      visibility  = "private"
    },
    {
      name        = "terraform-testapp"
      description = "Test web app "
      visibility  = "private"
      variables   = ["STORAGEACCOUNT","HOSTURL"]
      secrets     = ["CLIENTID", "CLIENTSECRET"]
    }
  ]
}

resource "github_repository" "repository" {
  for_each = local.repos

  name               = each.value.name
  description        = each.value.description
  visibility         = each.value.visibility
}

resource "github_actions_variable" "variable" {
  for_each      = merge([
    for repo in local.repos : {
      for variable in try(local.repos.variables, []) : 
      join("-", repo, variable = > {
        name = variable
        repo = repo
      }
    }
  ]...)

  repository = each.value.repo
}

resource "github_actions_secrets" "secrets" {
  for_each      = merge([
    for repo in local.repos : {
      for secret in try(local.repos.secret, []) : 
      join("-", repo, secret = > {
        name = secret
        repo = repo
      }
    }
  ]...)
  
  repository = each.value.repo
}

